# Specifying preseed/late_command as a shell script in Ubuntu preseed

Tags: boot, system-installation, iso, preseed

I am attempting to [specify a `preseed/late_command`](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/s390x/apbs04.html) as a shell script that enables the systemd `tmp.mount` unit. Executing of a shell script in `late_command` fails with error code 127 indicating confusingly that `/bin/sh` doesn't exist on the target. **What do I need to modify here to run a late_command shell script on the target?**

My `ubuntu-server-custom.seed` contains:

```
d-i     preseed/late_command                        string  cp \
    -a /cdrom/preseed/tmp_mount.sh /target/usr/sbin/; \
    chroot /target '/bin/sh /usr/sbin/tmp_mount.sh --need-target-bash --preseed-late-command';
```

(Note: newlines only added here for readability. The `--flags` to `sh` are hijacked from https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/18411.)

Also tried:

```
in-target '/bin/sh /usr/sbin/tmp_mount.sh';
```

with same error message and exit code.

`/preseed/tmp_mount.sh` exists on the ISO.

`tmp_mount.sh` looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

/bin/cp -aT /usr/share/systemd/tmp.mount /etc/systemd/system/tmp.mount
/bin/chmod 644 /etc/systemd/system/tmp.mount
/bin/sed -i -r 's/^Options=.*/Options=mode=1777,noatime,noexec,nodev,nosuid,size=4G/g' /etc/systemd/system/tmp.mount
/bin/systemctl unmask tmp.mount
/bin/systemctl enable tmp.mount
/bin/echo 'tmpfs /tmp tmpfs mode=1777,noatime,noexec,nodev,nosuid,size=4G 0 0' >> /etc/fstab
/bin/echo 'tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs defaults,nodev,nosuid,noexec 0 0' >> /etc/fstab
```

Booting from ISO errors with:

> Execution of preseeded command failed with error code 127.

I am able to push through the boot process and log in. Examining `/var/log/installer/syslog` I see:

[image]

I can also confirm that the script does actually exist on the target:

```
$ file /usr/sbin/tmp*
/usr/sbin/tmp_mount.sh: Bourne-Again shell script...
```

So what's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this working with some minor adjustments to the `late_command` invocation:

- Use `in-target` rather than `chroot /target`
- Remove trailing semicolon (possible this was being interpreted as part of file name but not sure)
- Make sure to add executable bits (don't see why this should be required when it is invoked through `sh`, but hey, whatever works)

End result from preseed:

```
d-i     preseed/late_command                        string  \
    cp -a /cdrom/preseed/tmp_mount.sh /target/usr/sbin/; \
    in-target chmod 700 /usr/sbin/tmp_mount.sh; \
    in-target /bin/sh /usr/sbin/tmp_mount.sh
```

Note that this will leave `/usr/sbin/tmp_mount.sh` present on the target filesystem. (I've chosen deliberately to leave it there.) You could remove it in a final `in-target /bin/rm /usr/sbin/tmp_mount.sh` if wanted.